# Can't get nested route to match using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble getting a nested route to match:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="work" component={Work}>
      <Route path=":slug" component={Sample} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Given this router, I can't match a route such as: `/work/sample-1` The app doesn't throw an error, nor can I log any statements on the `Sample` class.

Even if I hard-code the value I'm attempting to match, it won't work. If I un-nest the route, and set the path to `work/:slug` it will work as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so you route for sample which is not working is <Route path="sample-1" component={Sample} /> ?

also can you try with <Route path="sample" component={Sample} />

Comment: I get: `bundle.js:28311 Warning: [react-router] Location "/work/sample" did not match any routes` when I attempt to match a hard-coded route path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the pattern I was looking for in the ["sidebar"](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/sidebar/app.js) example on the React Router Github Page

I nested the route:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="work" component={Work}>
      <Route path=":slug" component={Sample} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Then in the `render` method of the `Work` component, I simply needed to display the children of the route, or the remainder of the component:

```
render() {
    <div>
        {this.props.children ||
        <div>
            {/* rest of "Work" component here */}
        </div>}
    </div>
}
```

Now, when I navigate to the nested route, my navigational item is selected, and the nested content is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing an `IndexRoute` within your nested `:slug route`:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="about" component={About} />
  <Route path="work" component={Work}>
    <IndexRoute component={SomeComponent}/> <<------ This guy
    <Route path=":slug" component={Sample} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

At least this is what the react router docs are showing: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md#adding-more-ui

Comment: I get the same result when adding an IndexRoute component that renders `<div>{this.props.children}</div>` the app just doesn't do anything. The path changes in the querystring, but the `console.log` statement in my destination component's `constructor` method is never called.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371951/how-to-properly-use-nested-routes-with-react-router?rq=1 got me on the right path. I'm very new to React, and I was missing `{this.props.children}` in the `Work` class. I'll need to re-think my component, as that's not what I intended to happen. The nested route works with or without the IndexRoute now. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Okay, glad you figured it out :) Be sure to add the `propTypes` object to your components, then react helps you when they are missing by writing warnings in the console: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation